# Sign out of PhpStorm to disable use

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Is there a way you can sign out of your PhpStorm account, so that the product isn't usable any more on your computer? So that it reverts back to a trial or similar.

I can't find anything in the docs to do this.

Thanks

Comment: How about uninstalling?

Comment: Yeah tried that but it remembered my details somehow

Answer (score 6):

User friendly option to unregister IDE [will be available in the next update](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132667).

Right now, your licensing information is stored in the Java Registry (actual location depends on the platform). We have [an internal tool that can clean it up](ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/jbclean.jar).

You can download and run it like this:

`java -jar jbclean.jar`

It will remove all the JetBrains keys from the Java Registry.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give that a go